# Добавление проекта на PyPi

Tags: python, lib, pypi

ребята, подскажите пожалуйста что делать. Я пытаюсь загрузить свой проект на PyPi, но оно просит у меня чтобы я включил 2-х факторку. Я включил и заново запустил, оно просит чтобы я создал токен, из за того что включена 2-х факторка. Я создал и создал файл .pypirc с нужными данными, но он все равно просит токен. Что делать?

вот сама ошибка:
`User ****** has two factor auth enabled, an API Token or Trusted Publisher must be used to upload in place of password.`

Answer (score 0):

Я в файле [.pypirc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pypirc/#using-a-pypi-token) написала:

```
[pypi]
username = __token__
password = <и вот тут токен>
```